# I need Git. Is it better to install command line tools (183mb) or `brew install git`?

Tags: command-line, homebrew, git

I think that it is better to install Git from Homebrew:

1. Less size
2. Install only what I need - I do not need LLVM compiler, for example.
3. Faster install
4. All packages in one place
5. No need to re-install command line tools after every macOS upgrade.

Comment: Do you need *only* git? Have tried to install brew and git alone, without XCode?

Comment: I do not installed XCode, only command-line-tools. But I think that for the future it is better to install Git from Homebrew.

Comment: Does Homebrew work after an OS upgrade - the systems API will chnage - an git is updated more often than the OS. Don't you need the command line tools for Homebrew?

Comment: I googled what is inside the command-line-tools, but found only `make`, `clang`, `perl`, LLVM compiler - looks like Homebrew does not need anything of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the command line tools to install Homebrew anyways, see: 
https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

> **Requirements**
>
> - An Intel CPU
> - macOS 10.12 or higher
> - Command Line Tools (CLT) for    Xcode: xcode-select --install, developer.apple.com/downloads or Xcode
> - A Bourne-compatible shell for installation (e.g. bash or zsh)

Answer (score 2):

As @Lizzan pointed out, the Command Line Tools are required in order to `brew install git`, but one advantage of the brewed git is that it is often updated more rapidly in response to security patches. For example, 3 days before this writing, homebrew git was updated to 2.19.1 to fix a security vulnerability, while the apple git is still at 2.17.1.

- https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/32757